# Let Mailchimp send daily summary when adding contacts with mailchimp API

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Mailchimp doesn't seem to send a daily summary of subsribers when they are added by the mailchimp API. Is there an option or someting in the API to enable this?

Comment: Short answer: no :( Long answer - you can kind of fake one in an automation!

Comment: automation with the mailchimp API?

Comment: No in the `AUTOMATION` tab you could do that.

[Here's a helpful link](https://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/working-with-automation/html/)